# how to display sent and received message in listview together

Tags: android

public void refreshSmsInbox() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
        int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
        int indexAddress = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("address");
        if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) return;

```
    arrayAdapter.clear();
    do {
        String str = "SMS From: " + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress) +
                "\n" + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody) + "\n";
        smsMessagesList.add(str);
    } while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

public void refreshSmsInbox() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null, null, null, null);

```
    if (smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body") < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) return;
    do {
        String contactName=smsInboxCursor.getString(smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
        String mess=smsInboxCursor.getString(smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body"));

        long timeMillis = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("date");
        Date date = new Date(timeMillis);
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YY");
        String dateText = format.format(date);

        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timeMillis),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeMillis) % TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeMillis) % TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1));

        MessageList message=new MessageList(contactName,mess,dateText,hms,R.drawable.receive);
        smsMessagesList.add(message);
    } while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());
}
```